# Construct harmonic function on noncompact manifold

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

$M$ is a non-compact Riemannian manifold, $p \in M$. Consider Dirichlet problems: $\Delta u = 0$ in ${B_p}\left( i \right)$ ($i = 1,2, \dots $), $u{|_{\partial {B_p}\left( i \right)}} = {f_i}$, ${f_i} \in {W^{1,2}}\left( {{B_p}\left( i \right)} \right)$. Then each of the functions has a unique weak solution ${u_i} \in {W^{1,2}}\left( {{B_p}\left( i \right)} \right)$. Suppose ${f_i}$ are uniformly bounded. Then can we find a subsequence of ${u_i}$ converging? And converging to a harmonic function defined on whole $M$.

Comment: @40votes:I should add"Suppose ${f_i}$ are uniformly bounded".

Comment: Have you tried using interior gradient  estimate to get equicontinuity on compact subsets?

Comment: By the way: not every non-compact manifold supports a nonzero bounded harmonic function. E.g., $\mathbb R^n$ does not.  On $\mathbb R^n$ the process you described will converge (along a subsequence, uniformly on compact subsets) to a constant function.

Comment: @40votes:I know they may converge to constant function.I just want to know why they converges to a harmonic function

Answer (score 3):

To avoid techcnical details about the 'order' of regularity of the solution of your Dirichlet problem, i suppose to work with precompact open set $ D_i $ with smooth boundary instead of the geodesic balls $ B_i(p) $ that in general are not smooth. Note that this choice can always be done. Therefore consider the problem

$$ \Delta u = 0 \;\; on \; D_i \; \; \; \; u|_{\partial D_i} = f_i \; \; \; (1) $$

and suppose $ f_i $ smooth on $ \partial D_i $.
By hypothesis $ ||f_i||_{\infty,\partial D_i} < C $, where $ C $ is independent on $ i $. By maximum principle $ ||f_i||_{\infty,D_i} < C $. Now let $ V \subset\subset U $ and let $ (U,\psi) $ be a local coordinate neighbourhood with compact closure. Let $ i_0 $ such that $ \forall i \geq i_0 $

$$ U \subset D_i $$

Let $ u_i $ be the solution of (1), let $ \tilde{u}_i= u_i \circ \psi^{-1} $ and let $ \tilde{U}= \psi(U) $.
 Let $ \tilde{L} $ be the laplace operator in local coordinates. Then $ \tilde{L}\tilde{u}_i =0 $ on $ \tilde{U} $ and $ ||\tilde{u}_i||_{\infty,\tilde{U}} < C $.

By Schauder Estimates we have that

$$ ||D^{\alpha}\tilde{u}_i||_{\infty,\tilde{V}} < C $$

for every multindex $ \alpha $. Therefore $ \{D^{\alpha}\tilde{u}_i: i \geq i_0 \} $ is uniformly bounded and equicontinous. By a repeated application of Ascoli's theorem we easily conclude that there exists $ \tilde{u} \in C^{2}(\tilde{V}) $ such that

$$ D^{\alpha}\tilde{u}_i \rightarrow D^{\alpha}\tilde{u} $$

uniformly on $ \tilde{V} $ for every $ |\alpha| \leq 2 $. Then $ \tilde{L}\tilde{u}=0 $ on $ \tilde{V} $. By regularity we have automatically that $ \tilde{u} \in C^{\infty} (\tilde{V}) $.Therefore $ \Delta u = 0 $ on $ V $ where $ u = \tilde{u} \circ \psi $.

Using a cover on $ M $ by local charts and repeating this argument for every open set of this covering we obtain a global harmonic function on $ M $.

Comment: My assumption is " ${f_i}$ is uniformly bounded". You have not explained clearly why there is such a $\mathop u\limits^ \sim  $

Comment: Can you be more precise? What step of the argument above is not clear?

Comment: :I prefer your discussion on the regularity. You assume ${f_i}$ smooth on  $\partial {D_i}$. I wonder whether your assumption is too strong. And What's the worst regularity of ${f_i}$ that can ensure  ${u_i}$ converge to a harmonic function (maybe constant function). Second,by Ascoli's theorem, there exists ${\tilde u}$(the regularity?), ${{\tilde u}_\alpha }$ such that ${{\tilde u}_i} \to \tilde u$ and ${D^\alpha }{{\tilde u}_i} \to {{\tilde u}_\alpha }$ So ${{\tilde u}_\alpha } = {D^\alpha }\tilde u$?